# Build-Jdk-Spec version in Manifest.Mf

Tags: maven, java-8, manifest, manifest.mf, logback-classic

I am using logback-classic 1.3.5 in my project but it is giving me UnsupportedOperationException. My project is on JDK 8 and when I saw in manifest file of logback-classic-1.3.5, it shows build-jdk-spec version as 19. I just want to know what exactly this "build-jdk-spec" version specifies

Answer (score 2):

The `build-jdk-spec` attribute is a "default" attribute added by the Maven "maven-archiver-plugin" ([reference](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/)).  The value is the value of the `${java.specification.version}` property for the build.  It is (I think) the JDK version of the JVM that was running the build tool (Maven).

---

The [build-jdk-spec] version number most likely doesn't signify anything that is relevant to your problem.  (It is NOT the the target Java version for the build!!)

The real cause of your problem can be deduced by looking at the details of the `UnsupportedOperationException` stacktrace.